# How can I click the next button on the Instagram registration webpage using python and selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, form-submit

This is the part of my code that not works:

```
#Click Next button 
submit_button = driver.find_element("xpath", '//button[text()="Next"]')
submit_button.click()

driver.close()
```

Everything else is working fine but I cant figure out how to click the "Next" button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4msdv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Click Next button using Java Script 
submit_button  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Next"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit_button )
```

Or this:

```
# Click Next button by using Selenium Waits
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Next"]')))
submit_button.click()
```